# Non-negative functions are a closed subset of $C_b(K)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach algebra $A=C_{b}(K)$ of all complex-valued bounded continuous functions on a completely regular Hausdorff space $K$ with the supremum norm, and let $C$ be the set $C:=\{g \in A: g(k) \geq 0 \text{ for all } k \in K \}.$ Then $C$ is a (topologically) closed subset of $A.$ Any help will be appreciated.

This is my **proof**.

Let $f_{n}$ be a sequence of elements in $C$ such that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ as $n \rightarrow \infty .$ It follows that $f_{n}(k) \rightarrow f(k)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty .$ Since for every $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $f_{n}(k) \geq 0$ for all $k \in K,$ it follows from the continuity of $f_{n}$ that $f(k) \geq 0$ for all $k \in K.$

Am not clear whether it is enough to say that since $f_{n}(k) \rightarrow f(k)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty ,$ then $f(k) \geq 0$ for all $k \in K.$

Comment: Uniform convergence implies (obviously) pointwise convergence, and $f_n \to f$ means exactly uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot Crostul. Will work along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, for each $k \in K$, the linear functional
$$
\varphi_k : C_b(K) \to \mathbb{C} \text{ given by } f\mapsto f(k)
$$
is continuous. The set you are looking at is
$$
\bigcap_{k\in K} \varphi_k^{-1}[0,\infty)
$$
which is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform convergence implies (obviously) pointwise convergence, and $f_n \to f$ means exactly uniform convergence.

Now $\{ f_n(k) \}_n \subseteq [0, + \infty)$ for all $k$, so its limit (i.e. $f(k)$) belongs to the closure of $[0, + \infty)$ in $\Bbb{C}$. But $[0, + \infty)$ is closed, so $f(k) \in [0, + \infty)$.